# How do you get rules to fire if the rule package is in another project?

Tags: maven, drools

I have a project proj1 that contains a bunch of rules,

I have another project proj2 that I call

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get(); 
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
```

How do I get proj2 to call proj1's rules?

my kmodule and pom is probably not set correctly, but I am not sure how to set them.

Comment: copy and paste the rule drls to access those in any other project. Useless question

Comment: I was hoping there was another way to do this. I want to keep the 2 projects separate. But thanks for the useless input.

Comment: well then for a useful output, better make a web service which serves rules strings on demand and fetch those from other application.